# git add -A vs git add file

Tags: git, gitignore, git-add

I got into the habit of using `.gitignore` and always doing `git add -A`, `git status` to check the modified files, then commit, so I don't need to remember about the files that I have modified and other developers don't need to know which files are ignored.

I still see other people doing `git add files` for each modified file.

So I was wondering whether there is any advantage of adding each file.

The question is: why not always using `git add -A` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are developing a feature, you may also fix some bugs or misspells that you found while browsing the code. Those corrections are not directly related to your feature, so maybe you want a separate commit for them. `git add [something]` allows you to work in this way.

Comment: Wouldn't branches or `stash`/`stash apply` be better for the job ?

Comment: Well I think it depends on the amount of corrections done. Branches and stashing is fine too, there are multiple way to do the same thing.

Comment: Anyway you answered to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's useful to be able to have a file in the git repository, not have it listed in `.gitignore`, and make local changes that you don't want to commit.

For me, this applies for example to Django's `settings.py` files, where I sometimes make changes to accommodate local database settings and the like. You still need to occasionally change bits of those files, e.g. adding bits to `INSTALLED_APPS`, which you can still commit using `git add -p`. The alternative would involve having a `settings.py.example` file, and adding `settings.py` to `.gitignore`, but then you need to manually "merge" changes from the example file into your actual settings file. If you haven't changed `settings.py`, you can just use git add .

Another use-case is if you have made two sets of changes, which you want to commit independently of each other. Then you can use `git add [-p] <file>`, commit, and repeat, as appropriately. Of course you need to ensure that your diffs are truly independent.